# why $x^2 - 25y^2 = 1$ cannot have integer solutions other than $( \pm 1,0)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

pell equations must have n to be nonsquared,so $x^2 - 25y^2 = 1$ is not a pell equation, but the thing is how can i show $x^2 - 25y^2 = 1$ have no integer solutions? or it has integer solutions.

Solve : $x^2-25y^2=1$

Comment: Factor the LHS (LHS = Left-Hand-Side).

Comment: $x=1$ and $y=0$ are integers.

Comment: the LHS can be odd just take x odd and y even.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given $x^2-25y^2=1$

$(x-5y)(x+5y)=1$
$1=-1 \cdot -1$ and $1=1 \cdot 1$ are the only ways to write $1$ as the product of two integers.
Hence we must have $x-5y=x+5y=1$ or $x-5y=x+5y=-1$ and so it gives the only solutions as $x= \pm 1$ and $y=0$ .

Comment: Ha! And here my first impulse was to use modular arithmetic. Too much knowledge can make you look for too complicated answers, sometimes.

Comment: Modular arithmetic is fine while proving that you have _no solutions_. Once you have one solution, it is all but useless.